# Query inside dictionary object with cosmos?

Tags: sql, json, azure-cosmosdb

I have a data structure like this:

```
{
  dictionary: {
    anotherThing: {
      id: "hello";
      type: "string"
    }
  }
}
```

another document:

```
{
  dictionary: {
    a: {
      id: "123";
      type: "number"
    },
    random: "cba"
  }
}
```

Is there a query in cosmos I can do that allows me to iterate over the keys in the dictionary object to query inside the nested objects (i.e. where `dictionary.x.type = "number"`)?

Answer (score 2):

1.use UDF. But the performance of UDF is worse and cost can be expensive.

2.change your schema like this:

```
dictionary: [
    {
        name:"a",
        value:{
            id: "123",
            type: "number"
        }
    }
]
```

Then you can try this sql:

`SELECT c FROM c JOIN d IN c.dictionary Where d['value'].type = "number"`